# creating a sequence of numbers, one per line in a file

Tags: files, utilities, arithmetic, text

Is there a way to create out of thin air, a file that is a sequence of numbers, starting at a given number, one per line?

something like

```
magic_command start 100 lines 5 > b.txt
```

and then, `b.txt` would be

```
100
101
102
103
104
```

Comment: no need to call it .txt

Answer (score 68, accepted):

There is already a command for this:

```
seq 100 104
```

will print these numbers on separate lines:

```
100
101
102
103
104
```

So just direct this output into a file:

```
seq 100 104 > my_file.txt
```

and `seq 100 2 104` will print in increments of two, namely: `100`, `102`, `104`

Comment: wooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooowwwwwwwwwww, you are a genius. That's it. I love unix more every second! Thanks.

Comment: is there a place where I can learn about little gems like seq? I am interested in commands that can create stuff out of thin air, like sequence of numbers, files that contain the same text line x times, commands that can generate sequence of letters "a, b, c, d..", stuff like that. thanks

Comment: @DigitalRobot: At some point you're probably going to find yourself just writing perl one-liners.

Comment: @SpaceDog Your love is misplaced. `seq` is from GNU Coreutils, not Unix. GNU even stands for GNU is Not Unix!

Answer (score 14):

Linux ships with the `seq` command which does exactly that. If you don't have the `seq` command, it's an easy one-liner:

```
i=100; while [ $i -le 104 ]; do echo $i; i=$((i+1)); done >b.txt
```

or in ksh/bash/zsh

```
for ((i=100; i<=104; i++)); do echo $i; done >b.txt
```

or in zsh

```
print -l {100..104} >b.txt
```

Comment: I love zsh more and more every day.

Comment: @Gilles your first example will continue forever because you never increment `$i`.

Comment: +1 for answering the question the OP would not have actually been able to ask ('i don't have seq, so i can't xyz') -- those sorts of answers are the real gems

Answer (score 9):

bash:

```
printf '%s\n' {100..105}
```

perl:

```
perl -le 'print for 100..104'
```

bc:

```
echo 'for (i = 100 ; i <= 104 ; ++i) i' | bc
```

dc:

```
echo '100 104 sb [p 1 + d lb !<m] sm lm x' | dc
```

Comment: +1 never seen anyone use bc or dc like that before

Comment: and it strikes me that your dc answer is uncommonly wry and upvote-worthy

Comment: It was unnecessarily complicated, but not on purpose, so I have simplified it now.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a space in front of most of them:

```
echo -e {100..104}\\n >numbers-file.txt
```

Without the space but with an extra command:

```
echo {100..104} | sed 's/ /\n/g' >numbers-file.txt
```

---

Edit for a bonus vim command (open vim):

```
i100[esc]qqyyp[ctrl-a]q2@q:w numbers-file.txt
```

For more numbers, increase `2` accordingly.

Comment: You can use printf(1) to not get the space at the start of the line: `printf '%s\n' {100..104}`

Answer (score 1):

Besides using `seq`, `while`, `for`, `printf`, `perl`, `echo` as shown in previous example, you can also use Python

```
python -c "print list(range(100,105))"
```

Example:

```
[user@linux ~]~ python -c "print list(range(100,105))"
[100, 101, 102, 103, 104]
[user@linux ~]~
```

Comment: _creating a sequence of numbers, **one per line**..._ and btw, this only works with python2.